# Functions/commands stored as array members in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

PHP code on test.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "DB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DB");
$cars = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab)){
    array_push($cars, array("id" => $row["Id"], "name" => $row["Name"], "color" => $row["Color"];
}
echo json_encode($cars);
```

Then jQuery/javascript code on html page:

```
var iNL1 = document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML;
var iNL2 = document.getElementById("itemnameLink2").innerHTML;
var iNL3 = document.getElementById("itemNameLink3").innerHTML;

var iNLarr = [iNL1, iNL2, iNL3];
i = 0;

$.get("test.php", function($cars){
    $.each($cars, function(){
        iNLarr[i] = this.name;
        i++;
    });
}, "json");
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work, I get null reference on iNLarr[i]. I'm guessing I can't store commands in an array like I've done. Can anyone tell me of a way of doing this.

Comment: `iNLarr[i].this.name;` Whats that supposed to do? Also the correct php is `json_encode` not `json.encode`

Comment: They're not "commands", they're references to DOM elements. And you can put them in an array. But they'd be null references if elements with those IDs weren't found - you'd need that JS code to be in a script element that is after the elements it references, and/or within a document ready or page onload handler.

Comment: Agree with Steve -- what is the expected result from that line? `iNLarr[i].this.name` is nonsensical.

Comment: P.S. Perhaps you mean `iNLarr[i].innerHTML = this.name;`?

Comment: Editted . for _ and iNLarr[i].this.name is supposed to change the html element innerHTML, although I forgot to put the innerHTML on the end. Done that now. Why would it return a null reference, those ids are there.

Comment: also changed iNLarr[i].this.name to iNLarr[i] = this.name but still getting back null reference for some reason.

Comment: looks like an `X-Y` problem. Logic would only work if you had 3 cars returned, one car for each element in DOM. If more than 3 `iNLarr[i]` will be undefined. Need to figure out what expected goals are

Comment: When you do the first assignments, you're just setting the variables to the inner HTML of those elements, and then you're copying those strings into the array. Assigning to the array does NOT go back and update the elements that the HTML came from.

Comment: ok, but is there a way of trying to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: start by explaining what it is you are needing to do with full detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put "commands" into an array, you need to put functions in:

```
iNRarr = [ 
    function(html) {
        document.getElementById("itemNameLink1").innerHTML = html;
    }, function(html) {
        document.getElementById("itemNameLink2").innerHTML = html;
    }, function(html) {
        document.getElementById("itemNameLink3").innerHTML = html;
    }
];
```

Then you call the functions like this:

```
$.get("test.php", function($cars){
    $.each($cars, function(i, car){
        if (iNLarr[i]) {
            iNLarr[i](car.name);
        }
    });
}, "json");
```

Comment: It's the value you want to store into the inner HTML. Don't you the `innerHTML = html` assignments?

Comment: no I don't do innerhtml = html assignments I'm very much a beginner, but what you said worked great help thanks.

Comment: ok how would I make so only the boxes that can be filled will be and the rest emptied. at the moment I'm saying that as long as there is an i car.name will change the html, what is there is no car and I want the box to be emptied.

Comment: It would be better to return an associative array from PHP, this will turn into an object in Javascript. Then you can loop over the cars in the DOM, and test `if (id in $cars)`. If it's in there, you change the HTML, otherwise you empty it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 3 cars returned and 3 elements, since you are using jQuery you can simplify this down to:

```
var $elements=$('#itemNameLink1,itemnameLink2,itemNameLink3');

$.get("test.php", function($cars){
    $.each($cars, function(i, car){
       $elements.eq(i).html(car.name);
    });
}, "json");
```

The `eq()` method is used to find element in collection by index and the first argument of `$.each` is index of array element when input is an array

Comment: adding more what? If you mean 1:1 can do the same thing using common class on the elements which makes for a very simple selector. Unfortunately you never explained the higher level expectations in question

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have a couple of things you might want to change:

First of all, you probably will get a syntax error on de `array_push` line. You didn't closed the `array_push` command, add `))` to it.

I don't think your definition of your javascript is correct. You won't be able to get it with `object[number]`. Try something like this:

```
var iNLarr = new Array();
iNLarr[0] = document.getElementById("itemNameLink1");
iNLarr[1] = document.getElementById("itemNameLink2");
iNLarr[2] = document.getElementById("itemNameLink3");
```

Another thing is that `iNLarr[i] = this.name;` won't work either. You probably mean:

```
iNLarr[i].innerHTML = $(this).attr('name');
```

So your complete could would be something like this:

Your PHP:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "DB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DB");
$cars = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab)){
    array_push($cars, array("id" => $row["Id"], "name" => $row["Name"], "color" => $row["Color"]));
}
echo json_encode($cars);

?>
```

Your HTML/Javascript:

```
<div id="itemNameLink1">1</div>
<div id="itemNameLink2">2</div>
<div id="itemNameLink3">3</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    var iNLarr = new Array();
    iNLarr[0] = document.getElementById("itemNameLink1");
    iNLarr[1] = document.getElementById("itemNameLink2");
    iNLarr[2] = document.getElementById("itemNameLink3");

    var i = 0;

    $.get("test.php", function($cars){

    $.each($cars, function(){
        iNLarr[i].innerHTML = $(this).attr('name');
        i++;
    });
    }, "json");

</script>
```